# Variables behaves strange - React Server Side Rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, server-side-rendering, conditional-operator, arrow-functions

I have a very strange problem with conditional operator inside arrow function in SSR React application. What I'd like to do is basically conditionally load component into variable but what I get is very strange variable/conditional behavior.

In case 1: I get correct behavior and strangeComponent gets null value

```
const isClient = false;
const strangeComponent = false ? (<Field
   name={name}
   isMulti
   component={({ input, ...rest }) => (
     <Select {...input} {...rest} searchable />)}
   closeMenuOnSelect={false}
   options={allSkills}
/>) : null;
```

In case 2: strangeComponent gets  component value, behaving like isClient is set to true while it is not.

```
const isClient = false;
const strangeComponent = isClient ? (<Field
   name={name}
   isMulti
   component={({ input, ...rest }) => (
     <Select {...input} {...rest} searchable />)}
   closeMenuOnSelect={false}
   options={allSkills}
/>) : null;
```

I should point out that isClient is not declared in any other place in code and strangeComponent is then rendered inside return() function. Both variables are declared inside arrow function.

Comment: What I'm suspecting right now is that my SSR config still runs through both parts of ternary operator and evaluates them (crash happens on <Select> component due to lack of window object) but end result of strangeComponent variable is actually valid. So the question changes to: why both parts are evaluated and how to stop it?

Comment: can you give the code part where you call the strangeComponent, as well as the arrow function you mentioned

Comment: sorry guys I already found the answer - I needed to conditionally import <Select> component with require() function, ternary operator worked just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Actually ternary operator worked fine, problem was with importing  component which was evaluated on SSR no matter if rendered or not. The answer was to conditionally import it via require().